# Extension Method Not Working on Inhierited Type

Tags: c#, extension-methods, covariance

I have the following class which implements an interface:

```
public class Category : IHierarchical<Category> {
    ...
}
```

I then have an inherited type called ProductCategory:

```
public class ProductCategory : Category {
    ...
}
```

Here's my IHierachical interface:

```
public interface IHierarchical<out T> where T : IHierarchical<T> {
    T Parent { get; }
    IEnumerable<T> Children { get; }
}
```

Finally I have the following extension method:

```
public static string MyExtension<T>(this T item) where T : IHierarchical<T> {
    ...
}
```

If I have an instance of type Category I can successfully call my extension method. However if my instance is of type ProductCategory I cannot call the extension method against it and instead I get the error:

```
The type 'ProductCategory' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic
type or method 'IHierarchicalExtensions.MyExtension<T>(T, string)'. There is no
implicit reference conversion from 'ProductCategory' to
'IHierarchical<ProductCategory>'.
```

I thought by making IHierachical covariant it would solve this issue. I'd appreciate it if someone could show me how this can be done. Thanks

Comment: That's probably because ProductCategory doesn't implement the interface, if you tried ProductCategory is IHierarchical, it'd give you false. If you make your child implement the interface as well, it'd work.

Comment: @artm Actually `ProductCategory` is `IHierarchical<Category>` which does not meet the restrain `where T : IHierarchical<T>`.

Comment: @juharr Didn't know that `ProductCategory is IHierarchical<Category>` with inheritanc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inferred type for `T` is `ProductCategory` and as the compiler error suggests, this does not implement `IHierarchical<ProductCategory>`. You can manually specify the type as `Category` however:

```
var pc = new ProductCategory();
pc.MyExtension<Category>();
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks cleaner than doing a cast to me.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `ProductCategory` does not meet the restraint `where T : IHierarchical<T>` because `ProductCategory` is actually `IHierarchical<Category>` because it inherits that from `Category`.  As for how to fix this is really up to what you are trying to accomplish.  You can either losen up the restraint or change `ProductCategory` to implement `IHierarchical<ProductCategory>` (It can still inherit from `Category`) or cast your `ProductCategory` to a `Category`, or finally specify the type for `T` as `Category` when you call your extension method.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have something like this:

```
Category c = new Category();
ProductCategory pc = new ProductCategory();

c.MyExtension();
pc.MyExtension();//Compiler error!
```

Your extension method allows `T` which means you can pass any type, your compile time type of `pc` is `ProductCategory`, so when you invoke `MyExtension`, T is of type `ProductCategory`.

What about the constraint `where T : IHierarchical<T>`?

It says that `ProductCategory` should be a `IHierarchical<ProductCategory>` clearly your `ProductCategory` is not. It is rather `IHierarchical<Category>` and so it doesn't compiles.

To fix it you may need a upcast to `Category`.

```
((Category)pc).MyExtension();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a `ProductCategory` item to `MyExtension`, `T` is inferred to be `ProductCategory`, so the constraint is `ProductCategory : IHierarchical<ProductCategory>`. It fails because `ProductCategory` only implements `IHierarchical<Category>`.

Covariance means that an `IHierarchical<ProductCategory>` object can be used where an `IHierarchical<Category>` is expected. What you are trying to do is the opposite. Thus you would need *contravariance* for this, but that is not the solution here (you can't have a `T Parent` property if `T` is contravariant).

To successfully use this code, you can specify the `T` in your call:

```
ProductCategory pc = ...;
pc.MyExtension<Category>();
```

This will succeed because the constraint becomes `IHierarchical<Category>` which `pc` satisfies.

Another solution is to use a non-generic interface, which the generic interface inherits, for the extension:

```
public interface IHierarchical {
    ...
}

public interface IHierarchical<out T> : IHierarchical where T : IHierarchical<T> {
    ...
}

public static string MyExtension(this IHierarchical item) {
    ...
}
```